# Marshalling String (But Not Byte Array) Inside Struct Causes AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte, marshalling

I have the following structure that I'm trying to marshal in C#:

- Length (4 bytes)
- Version (4 bytes)
- MachineID (16 bytes)

The problem I'm having is getting the `MachineID` as a `string` in C#. In the structure, I specify `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 24)]` at the top and `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 16)]` for the `MachineID`. But when I do this, I get the `System.AccessViolationException` is thrown.

If I change the `MachineID` to be `byte[]` and specify `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]` it works fine.

Below is code that works with a `byte[]` but not a `string`. The `MachineID` in ASCII form is `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO`.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 24)]
    struct Valid
    {
        public uint Length;
        public uint Version;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public byte[] MachineId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 24)]
    struct Invalid
    {
        public uint Length;
        public uint Version;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 16)] 
        public string MachineId;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var bytes = new byte[]
        {
            0x58, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x4D, 0x4E, 0x4F, 0
        };

        var pinnedBuffer = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var ptr = pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        // Works!
        Debug.Assert(bytes.Length == Marshal.SizeOf<Valid>());

        var trackerData1 = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Valid>(ptr);

        Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", trackerData1.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", trackerData1.Version);
        Console.WriteLine("MachineId: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(trackerData1.MachineId));

        // Doesnt work!
        Debug.Assert(bytes.Length == Marshal.SizeOf<Invalid>());

        // Throws System.AccessViolationException
        var trackerData2 = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Invalid>(ptr);

        Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", trackerData2.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", trackerData2.Version);
        Console.WriteLine("MachineId: {0}", trackerData2.MachineId);

        pinnedBuffer.Free();

        Console.In.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you [run this code in IDEOne](http://ideone.com/l7sfbU), you'll see that it throws the `System.AccessViolationException` when it tries to marshal the `string` and it's not just my computer.

What I'm curious is why does it work for a byte array but not a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to marshal it as `ByValTStr` for this to work:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
public string MachineId;
```

Here's [`the example`](http://ideone.com/J0bHhC).